# Bug: editing my bio pulls up some old version

Tags: bug, profile-page

When I try to edit [my bio for the site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/47085/dan-dascalescu), SE pulls an older version of it. My bio starts with "Currently building [iDoRecall](http://idorecall.com)" but when I edit, I get an older version starting with "As a full-stack engineer":

[image]

Comment: Does trying to edit your bio on puzzling do the same?

Comment: And what about SO and U&L?

Comment: All three pull the correct bio, but they use the new profile UI.

Comment: Didn't realize U&L finally got updated. Do you have existing accounts on any other un-updated sites?

Comment: [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/10820/dan-dascalescu) pulls the correct bio when editing.

Comment: Just here then. Do you recall when and on which site you last updated your profile? I don't see an edit here.

Comment: Most likely on May 19. I edited my profile across the [top SE sites I'm registered with](http://stackexchange.com/users/8216/dan-dascalescu?tab=accounts) going down the list, and probably the last one was [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/5972/dan-dascalescu?tab=profile), which uses the new profile system.

Comment: [Same bug on Engineering.SE](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328/editing-my-profile-pulls-an-older-version).